# Using R to redistribute character values across multiple columns in a dataset

Tags: r

I am a new R user with a survey dataset that asks respondents (indicated by their IDs 100,101,102, and 103 in rows) to list common crimes and security problems in their neighborhoods. Types of incidents, crime1-crime3, are distributed across the columns. I know that the dataset is not well organized, but this is the structure of the output generated by Google form surveys for "select all that apply" questions.

I would like to write R code to reconfigure the dataset so that each type of crime/problem (for example, theft) has its own column. Then the character values could be replaced with 1. I have reorganized a small excerpt of the larger dataset by hand to show the end result I am looking for. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I initially tried to use gather() to collect all character values into one column and then redistribute into new columns but was unable to get it to work.

### Original dataset:

```html
respondentID  crime1 crime1  crime3

100  vandalism  other  0 
101  other  0  0
102  drugs  theft  other
103  drugs  theft  vandalism
```

### Trying to convert to:

```html
respondentID  drugs theft  vandalism other
100  0  0  1  1 
101  0  0  0  1
102  1  1  0  1
103  1  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, convert from wide to long:

```
df <- structure(list(respondentID = 100:103, crime1 = c("vandalism", 
  "other", "drugs", "drugs"), crime1.1 = c("other", "0", "theft", 
  "theft"), crime3 = c("0", "0", "other", "vandalism")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -4L))

df_long <- df %>% 
  gather(key="crime_no", value="crime", -respondentID) %>% 
  select(-crime_no) %>% 
  filter(crime != "0")
```

Explanation: first line loads your data (you should use `dput` next time you ask a question). Second line converts to a format with one column per crime. We do not need the "crime_no" column, as you are not interested whether a crime was 1, 2 or 3. Finally, we don't need the `0` crimes (we will fill that out automatically later).

Now, calculate the statistics:

```
df_stat <- df_long %>% group_by(respondentID, crime) %>% summarise(n=n())
```

Explanation: while in your example data each person committed a type of crime only once, I assume that this is not the general case, and some times you will see other numbers. We first group the data by respondent and crime, and next we count how many times each combination occurs.

And back to wide format:

```
df_wide <- df_stat %>% spread(key=crime, value=n, fill=0)
```

Explanation: we now convert to the "wide" format, where each crime has its own column. We use parameter `fill=0`, so if there is missing data (i.e., a person did not commit a given crime), then we will insert `0` rather than `NA`.

And here is your result:

```
  respondentID drugs other theft vandalism
         <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1          100     0     1     0         1
2          101     0     1     0         0
3          102     1     1     1         0
4          103     1     0     1         1
```

Next time you ask a question, please

1. use `dput` so we can easily load your example data
2. show some code: how did you try to tackle the problem on your own?

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions.

Comment: Yes, and as an academic teacher with 20 years of teacher practice I strongly recommend of trusting my experience to recognize when a student shows interest and effort and when not. As bad questions go, this one was actually not too far off the mark. They showed some data (and clearly had trouble with the interface), they also mentioned `gather` which showed that they were on the right track. In short, I don't think any of the points mentioned in the guidelines really fits.

Comment: No attempt shown with coding, as what you mentioned in your answer as well. Showing some data does not count as [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and does not show the specific problems they are running into. Also, this is not a coding-service. It is better to guide them to make a better question, rather than blatantly answering the question, which would just encourage the behavior.